# Tools like Fiddler for SSL encrypted TCP traffic?

Tags: ssl, encryption, tcp, fiddler, wireshark

I'm have sniffed some traffic from an application using wireshark but the application uses SSL for encryption.

Is there any tool like Fiddler that will work with the TCP protocol and decrypt the traffic?

UPDATE

I have tried using Tcp Catcher.

I can't get it to capture the traffic from the application. Under the settings tab I checked tcp proxy and set the server and port and checked monitor ssl comunication. I also added a rule in etc/hosts to redirect the server to localhost and checked transparent proxy in tcp catcher. The application still runs but tcp catcher doesn't see any traffic. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Why don't you use fiddler ?

Comment: You can use wireshark but you need the encryption key so will only work if you control app and server, see [this](http://packetpushers.net/using-wireshark-to-decode-ssltls-packets/) for instance.

Comment: @Superdrac Fiddler only supports http and https. I'm interested in tcp. ManyRootsofAllEvil I don't have the private key so that won't work.

Comment: What about this one ? 

http://www.tcpcatcher.org/

Comment: ssldump? if you are in *nix environment

Answer (score 2):

You're asking: `"How can I decrypt arbitrary TLS-protected TCP traffic without the private key."` The answer is, of course, you cannot do that. That's why anyone uses TLS to begin with.

You can, as other commenters have suggested, use tools that replace the network functions in the client software with other versions that emit unprotected traffic, but doing that requires that you are in a position to replace such functions, and recommending such a tool would work much better if you share more information about what sort of client you're trying to use.

Comment: what information do you need? I need a tool that acts as a man in the middle like fiddler does. tcp catcher seems to have that option but I can't get it to work over tcp (only over https so far).

Comment: What is the client application?

Comment: Kik for android. I'm running it using bluestacks.

Comment: Unless you have the ability to thunk functions on "Kik for Android" (which presumably requires rooting and native code) then the only way to do this would be to 1> Hope that the client doesn't validate certificates, or accepts certs in the Android certificate store, 2> Redirect the client's requests to your MITM (e.g. using iptables) and then 3> find an application that allows arbitrary MITM of TCP/IP connections.

Answer (score 0):

You should already be able to do this with Wireshark, as documented in its [SSL page](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL).

Older versions of Wireshark needed you to have the server's private key, and only worked with non-DHE cipher suites.

Newer versions can use the pre-master secret directly (read "*Using the (Pre)-Master-Secret*" section). This is something you may be able to get from the client side too in some cases (provided it has debugging options to do so). Here are a couple of links from that section of the Wireshark wiki:

- [Ask.Wireshark: Follow SSL stream using Master-key and Session-ID](http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/4229/follow-ssl-stream-using-master-key-and-session-id)
- [Security.SE: Decrypting TLS in Wireshark when using DHE_RSA ciphersuites](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/42350/2630)

Comment: Very cool that Wireshark now has the ability to use the Pre-master-secret, but it's probably quite non-trivial to get that out of the client unless the framework is specifically designed to release it.

Comment: @EricLaw, you're right. As far as I understand, applications relying on NSS should be able to do so by using the right environment variable, the JSSE will also show it [when using the javax.net.debug=ssl system property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html), but doing it in general can be tricky, especially on a mobile device.